# Can't run Jest with typescript in React Native

Tags: typescript, react-native, jestjs, storybook, ts-jest

### The problem

I'm trying to setup **Jest with Typescript** on my **React Native** project but it just won't work. I have followed the documentation on both jest/ts-jest to configure it but it still throws following errors (based on how i edit the config files)

```
\Development\stories\__tests__\App.test.tsx:14
    (0, react_native_1.render)(<App_1.default />);
                               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1678:14)
```

or

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

> 1 | import { getStorybookUI } from '@storybook/react-native';
    | ^
  2 |
  3 | import './storybook.requires';
  4 |
```

### Stack

##### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "stories",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "update-stories": "sb-rn-get-stories --config-path .storybook/.ondevice",
    "prestart": "yarn update-stories",
    "storybook-watcher": "sb-rn-watcher --config-path .storybook/.ondevice",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.3.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-controls": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.12",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions": "^6.0.1-beta.8",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-backgrounds": "^6.0.1-beta.8",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-controls": "^6.0.1-beta.8",
    "@storybook/addon-ondevice-notes": "^6.0.1-beta.8",
    "@storybook/addon-react-native-web": "^0.0.18",
    "@storybook/react": "6.3",
    "@storybook/react-native": "^6.0.1-beta.8",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^11.2.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.1.1",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.4",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.18.9",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^29.1.2",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.18.9",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.8.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
  }
}
```

##### tsconfig.json

```json
// prettier-ignore
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/react-native/tsconfig.json",     /* Recommended React Native TSConfig base */
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */

    /* Completeness */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  }
}
```

##### tsconfig.spec.json

```json
// tsconfig.spec.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-native", // Switching to "react" throws "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"
  }
}
```

##### jest.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        tsconfig: 'tsconfig.spec.json',
      },
    ],
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx', 'json', 'node'],

  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    'node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@react-native|react-native|react-clone-referenced-element|@react-native-community|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base)',
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect',
    '<rootDir>/__mocks__/globalMock.js',
  ],
};
```

##### babel.config.js

```js
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
  module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

##### App.test.tsx

```ts
/**
 * @format
 */

import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';

import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';

test('renders correctly', () => {
  render(<App />);
});
```